# How to get refreshed HTML content data after clicking search/pushbutton?

Tags: html, excel, vba

I set values of different fields of webpage using VBA code and then click a search button. After clicking the search button HTML content of page will be refreshed. I want to retrieve refreshed data.

I am getting HTML content using below code

**Process steps**:

1. Get the default content of a url and store it in a HtmlFile object

   ```
   Web_URL = "http://www.ksestocks.com/Announcements"
   'Create HTMLFile Object
   Set HTML_Content = CreateObject("htmlfile")
   'Get the WebPage Content to HTMLFile Object
   With CreateObject("msxml2.xmlhttp")
       .Open "GET", Web_URL, False
       .send
       HTML_Content.Body.Innerhtml = .responseText
   End With
   ```
2. Set values of different fields of the webpage using

   `HTML_Content.getElementsByTagName`
3. Perform click event on "Search Database" element

   ```
   Set elems = HTML_Content.getElementsByTagName("input")
   For Each e In elems
       If (e.getAttribute("value") = "Search Database") Then
            e.Click
   ```
4. After clicking element form is posted/page is reloaded.
5. I want to get the new html content again of the form post.
6. Do further processing on the html content.

I am unable to perform steps 5 and 6. I need to know what code to write for step 4.